# no matching constructor for initialization of 'aria2: : DHKeyExchange

Tags: aria2

I was compiling and installing Aria2 and encountered following error when running `make install`:

```
InternalDHKeyExchange. Cc: 117:5: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
'aria2: : DHKeyExchange: : n' (aka 'ulong < 1024 >')

Make [2]: *** [internaldhkeyexchange.lo] Error 1
Make [1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
Make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

There was no error in `./ifconfigure make-j4`.

Hope to get help.